# Can I send a push notification to a phone which I only have its number?

Tags: android

Basically I'm asking about the Client Id - How do I contact someone without having them contact me first?

Comment: Are you referring to Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) or something else?

Comment: C2MD could be good too. Any push technology is good. I just want to know if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your requirement implies sending an SMS or MMS. I can't think of any other protocol or standard that uses phone number as destination for the data.